# .NET already contains a definition for event variable starting with add_

Tags: c#, .net

I'm struggling to understand why these errors/warnings are occurring the below.  Most importantly the error, because it's blocking the compile.
I can "fix" the error by following the proposed naming convention in the messages and begin the variables with upper case characters.
But I just don't understand why .NET is throwing the error.

| Severity | Code | Description | Project | File | Line | Suppression State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Error | CS0102 | The type 'Class1' already contains a definition for 'add_a' | ClassLibrary1 | ClassLibrary1\Class1.cs | 10 | Active |
| Message | IDE1006 | Naming rule violation: These words must begin with upper case characters: add_a | ClassLibrary1 | ClassLibrary1\Class1.cs | 8 | Active |
| Message | IDE1006 | Naming rule violation: These words must begin with upper case characters: add_a | ClassLibrary1 | ClassLibrary1\Class1.cs | 8 | Active |
| Message | IDE1006 | Naming rule violation: These words must begin with upper case characters: a | ClassLibrary1 | ClassLibrary1\Class1.cs | 10 | Active |
| Message | IDE1006 | Naming rule violation: These words must begin with upper case characters: a | ClassLibrary1 | ClassLibrary1\Class1.cs | 10 | Active |

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public event myHandler add_a;

        public event myHandler a;

        public delegate void myHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is only one error, the others are just warnings. An event implies internal methods such as `add_YourEvent` and `remove_YourEvent` so there is a naming clash. See the spec with reserved names for events https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#143103-member-names-reserved-for-events

Comment: thanks, that's the answer

Answer (score 0):

Copying Charlieface comment, which is the answer.

An event implies internal methods such as add_YourEvent and remove_YourEvent so there is a naming clash.

See the spec with reserved names for events
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#143103-member-names-reserved-for-events